# App won't post text on Facebook wall

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to public text on user Facebook wall. I have some strange problem, and I couldn't find answer for my questing. 
When I tried to post something on wall my app launch Safari/FacebookApp and after I accepted that, I agree to app post things on wall my iPhone back to my app without posting on wall. 
Someone have that case? 
This is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"something"];

//Share the item
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem. create new app. on facebook solved my problem. create new app and copy new app ID into your project.